# Access (and count) just object values from Postgres JSONB array of objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column in a Postgres database. I'm storing an array of JSON objects, each with a single key-value pair. I'm sure I could have designed this better, but for now I'm stuck with this.

```
id | reviews
------------------
 1 | [{"apple": "delicious"}, {"kiwi": "not-delicious"}]
 2 | [{"orange": "not-delicious"}, {"pair": "not-delicious"}]
 3 | [{"grapes": "delicious"}, {"strawberry": "not-delicious"}, {"carrot": "delicious"}]
```

Suppose this table is called `tasks`. While the keys in each of these objects are not predictable, the values are. For each row, I'd like to know the number of "delicious" and number of "not-delicious" values in the `reviews` array.

Edit for clarification:

I'm looking for the delicious/not-delicious counts for each `id`/row in the above table. Sample desired output:

```
id | delicious | not_delicious
-------------------------------
 1 |         1 |             1
 2 |         0 |             2
 3 |         2 |             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say r is your table:

```
so=# select * from r;
                                       reviews
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"apple": "delicious"}, {"kiwi": "not-delicious"}]
 [{"orange": "not-delicious"}, {"pair": "not-delicious"}]
 [{"grapes": "delicious"}, {"strawberry": "not-delicious"}, {"carrot": "delicious"}]
(3 rows)
```

then:

```
so=# with j as (select jsonb_array_elements(reviews) a, r, ctid from r)
select jsonb_object_keys(a), a->>jsonb_object_keys(a),ctid from j;
 jsonb_object_keys |   ?column?    | ctid
-------------------+---------------+-------
 apple             | delicious     | (0,1)
 kiwi              | not-delicious | (0,1)
 orange            | not-delicious | (0,2)
 pair              | not-delicious | (0,2)
 grapes            | delicious     | (0,3)
 strawberry        | not-delicious | (0,3)
 carrot            | delicious     | (0,3)
(7 rows)
```

I used ctid as row identifier, cos I have no other column and did not want long `reviews`

and obviously aggregation of delicious per row:

```
so=# with j as (select jsonb_array_elements(reviews) a, r, ctid from r)
select ctid, a->>jsonb_object_keys(a), count(*) from j group by a->>jsonb_object_keys(a),ctid;
 ctid  |   ?column?    | count
-------+---------------+-------
 (0,1) | delicious     |     1
 (0,3) | delicious     |     2
 (0,1) | not-delicious |     1
 (0,2) | not-delicious |     2
 (0,3) | not-delicious |     1
(5 rows)
```

**for updated post**

```
so=# with j as (select jsonb_array_elements(reviews) a, r, ctid from r)
, n as (
 select ctid,a->>jsonb_object_keys(a) k from j
)
, ag as (
select ctid
, case when k = 'delicious' then 1 else 0 end deli
, case when k = 'not-delicious' then 1 else 0 end notdeli
from n
)
select ctid, sum(deli) deli, sum(notdeli) notdeli from ag group by ctid;
 ctid  | deli | notdeli
-------+------+---------
 (0,1) |    1 |       1
 (0,2) |    0 |       2
 (0,3) |    2 |       1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I'll clarify my question, since this isn't quite what I'm looking for. Apologies, but thank you for this response.

Comment: @user94154 I got other result numbers, but they look correct to me

Comment: Thanks for the update and catching my error. I updated my post to fix that.

Comment: if the answer acceptable, please accept and/or upvote it